# Stuck with "sh: 0: Can't open bower". What am I missing?

Tags: linux, unix, bower, bower-install

Stuck with "sh: 0: Can't open bower". What am I missing?

I'm root.

Did an:

```
su - userwithoutpassword
```

then,

```
sh bower install something
```

I get "sh: 0: Can't open bower". It seems that sh is unable to find bower even if I'm able to execute it just fine anywhere else?

This might be a unix problem, not bower related. Do I need to export a path or something?

Comment: Which linux distribution are you using? And how did you install bower?